# How to properly configure multiple routes in lite-server

Tags: angular, browser-sync, lite-server

I'm using the [lite-server](https://github.com/johnpapa/lite-server) to develop an Angular application. I have the following project structure, very simple:

```
build/
    foo/
        index.html (references foo.js script)
    bar/
        index.html (references bar.js script)
foo.js
bar.js
bsconfig.json
```

What a I want to do is to access `localhost:8000/foo` and get `foo/index.html` loading `foo.js` script as well as access `localhost:8000/bar` and get `bar/index.html` loading `bar.js`.

I've read the [Browsersync options](https://www.browsersync.io/docs/options) documentation and tried configuring the `bs-config.json` file using `routes` but I couldn't get it working.

Answer (score 0):

You may add routes to the server object

```
routes : {"/foo" : "build/foo", "/bar" : "build/bar" }
```

You may put your foo.js and bar.js under the "foo" and "bar" folders respectively and reference them locally, or leave the on the project's folder and reference it as "/foo.js" and "/bar.js"

Answer (score -1):

you may set `base href` to point to different folders in the index.html files
,

```
  <base href="/foo/">

  <base href="/bar/">
```

Also you have to configure where you are serving main package from in `system.config` file.

Comment: I've set the `base href` and it doesn't work. I think it's a `lite-server` configuration issue.